# Run on IIS server shell command in php

Tags: php, shell, iis, cmd

I use an IIS server and I want to execute some shell commands, but do not know exactly what the problem is.

For example, you want to set the time, or to create a new user, or whatever, does absolutely nothing (return null)

```
<?php
   $output = shell_exec("time 11:50 PM");

   echo '<pre>';
   print_r($output);
   echo '</pre>';
?>
```

And I thought to show username that is connected to see if with Administrator rights or not.

```
"echo %username%"
```

instead return my username, it returns me "COMPUTERNAME-PC$"
How can I run shell commands as administrator?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is you can't as it's configured now. You're restricted to the application pool identity. More than likely you're using the `NETWORK SERVICE` user, which is why you're getting the PC name as the username.

The solution would be to change the application pool identity to a user that the permissions you need. But you could still run into issues if User Account Control (UAC) is enabled, and you run a command that requires elevation which it sounds like you want to do.